# 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' using skearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to train and test a Naive Bayes model using scikit-learn but am experiencing issues. I have a dataset in CSV format with labelled emails (1 or 0). The code is:

```
def nb_model(dataset):
  ds = dataset
  count_vec = CountVectorizer()
  mail_tokens = count_vec.fit_transform(ds['mail']) #analyse and vectorize text within sample_ds['mail']

  
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mail_tokens, ds['phishing'], test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
  
  from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
  classifier = MultinomialNB()
  classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
  res = classifier.score(x_test, y_test)
  print(res)

  #result calculations
  # from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
  # pred = classifier.predict(x_train)
  # print(classification_report(y_train, pred))
  # print("acc: ", accuracy_score(y_train, pred))

  sample = "urgent action required"
  sample = sanitize_text(sample)
  print(sample)
  data = [sample]
  
  var = count_vec.transform(data).toarray()
  result = classifier.predict(var)
  print("sample result: ", result)
```

Previously, instead of `mail_tokens = count_vec.fit_transform(ds['mail']) #analyse and vectorize text within sample_ds['mail']` I had `count_vec(analyzer=sanitize_text).fit_transform(ds['mail'])` as that's what the tutorial I was  [following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNLPt02RwF0) said to reference. I do have a `sanitize_text()` which cleans the data (stopwords, punctuation etc)

Once the model is trained, I want to test a sample string to predict whether it is spam or not (1 or 0). I'm quite certain there is some issue with how I've declared the vectorizer. The error is below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-a140922fd218> in <module>()
----> 1 preprocess_text()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     69     """
     70     if lower:
---> 71         doc = doc.lower()
     72     if accent_function is not None:
     73         doc = accent_function(doc)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I tried multiple declarations of the CountVectorizer function but results in different errors, such as 'Vocuabulary not fitted' etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [sample] # Here you make a list
```

And the error says `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`. Though, earlier you've used the same CountVectorizer to transform your training data, which were a Pandas Series, not a list (text Pandas Series supports `lower()` method, when list doesn't). And applying `lower()` method is must-have part of every text vectorization process, just like one used by sklearn's `CountVectorizer`

**So, you need to transform your test data to Pandas Series**.

Comment: Hi. I tried adding `data_pd = pd.Series(data)` but the same error occurs. However, I tried changing the CountVectorizer declaration to `count_vec = CountVectorizer(analyzer=sanitize_text)` and now it kind of works. The issue now is the model has a very low accuracy rate of 60% which leads me to think there is another issue in how the model is trained or the dataset itself. I will post the confusion matrix in the next comment.

Comment: Training```0       1.00      1.00      1.00      2534
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00      1883

    accuracy                           1.00      4417
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      4417
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      4417```

Comment: Testing```Train Acc:  1.0
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.58      1.00      0.73      1060
           1       1.00      0.06      0.12       834

    accuracy                           0.59      1894
   macro avg       0.79      0.53      0.43      1894
weighted avg       0.76      0.59      0.46      1894```. I also have an unusually low amount of columns for the `mail_tokens.shape`, which outputs `tokens shape:  (6311, 6179)`.

Comment: You should have used `pd.Series([data])`. As we can see from your matrices, train accuracy is 1.0, though, the test on is ~0.6, which 99% of time means overfitting. You should try a few differect classifiers (e.g. Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, SGD)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The thing is I've seen tutorials use the same classifier and they attain rates of >0.9 so I don't know why mine is so low. Any comments on the shape of `mail_tokens`?

Comment: I just tried adding the brackets to `data` but it now crashes my Colab project. The error produced is from the `sanitize_text` function which uses a `try` to catch any errors when removing punctuation, stopwords etc.

Comment: What part of `mail_tokens.shape` you are not satisfied with? The 1st number here is the number of rows in your df, the 2nd one is the length of your CountVectorizer's vocabulary. You can increase it by adding bigrams (two-word combinations) to your vocabulary, it will increase its length significantrly and may increase accuracy `(ngram_range=(1,2)`). Also, some other vectorizer may help here (e.g. TfIdfVectorizer).

Comment: I feel like the length of the vocabulary should be a lot longer. At the moment, the number suggests that less than one unique word is gained from each row of data which doesn't add up to me. I've seen people with less rows and vocab lengths of 40,000! The code you mentioned, where should this be specified. I'll try it and see if it helps.

Comment: Well, the length of vocabulary depends not only on number of rows. It depends on heterogeneity of data, on your preprocessing technique and a few more things. `ngram_range=(1,2)` should be specified in CountVectorizer's initialization.

Comment: Ok I think my my perception of the vocabulary is maybe wrong then. I tried adding the `ngram_range` but it had no effect on the shape or accuracy of the testing. Just to be sure, it should be `count_vec = CountVectorizer(analyzer=sanitize_text, ngram_range=(1,2))` right? Also, my project is still crashing due to the `pd.Series([data]). Any ideas?

Comment: Vectorizer initialization looks fine, though, there must be some vocabulary length change when adding ngram range. Idk, why pd.Series crashes your project, are you using Jupyter? Show me the error if possible. And try different vectorizer

Comment: I'm using Colab. There's no error produced as such but the crash log shows this ```Apr 5, 2022, 12:04:26 PM WARNING WARNING:root:kernel 5ed3e1d3-f0c2-47a0-ba79-8bb29b7d8d40 restarted```. It also causes the `sanitize_text()` to trigger ```except Exception:
      print("Error processing dataset. Please relaunch program and try again. \n")
      exit()```

Comment: Colab usually displays some error message in the bottom left corner. The most common error in colab - the OOM one, which is possible when creating vocabulary.

Comment: I can't see any error apart from 'Unknown error caused project to crash. Relaunching'. On another note, would you know what `analyzer=sanitize_text` means exactly? Because any vectorizer I use without that specified returns the list lower error shown on the original post

Comment: Ananyzer argument specifies the type of text tokenization (word-tokens, char-tokens, etc). You shouldn't thonk about it and leave default value, better for you is fixing your input data, so please provide the output of 
`sample = "urgent action required"
  sample = sanitize_text(sample)
  print(sample)`
And try to feed your count vectorizer with data without wrapping it to list

Comment: Sorry but I'm don't understand. My vectorizer doesn't sucessfully initialise without `analyzer=sanitize_text`. All my `sanitize_text` function does is remove punctuation, stopwords and return data in a list I believe. This is an example of a row of data before and after it's passed to`sanitize_text`: Before: `You have 24 hours to confirm your PayPal perso...` After `[24, hours, confirm, paypal, personal, informa...]`. I hope this makes sense